# Регулярное выражение, с определенными символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Помогите составить RegExp для кириллицы.

Необходимо найти в строке определенные символы.

Пробовал так, работает некорректно

```
/[ГОАОДРАЗНЯ]/ui
```

То есть, есть слово **загородная** и регулярка должна определить его по буквам.

Спасибо.

Comment: `/[ГОАОДРАЗНЯ]+/ui` ?

Comment: @yuri, Так тоже не работает.

Comment: У вас слово в каком регистре написано?

Comment: В uppercase. Мне необходимо, чтобы в слове были ТОЛЬКО эти символы Г О А О Д Р А З Н Я.

Comment: По идее должно работать. Вы уверены, что всё правильно делаете?

Comment: @Yuri, Да. Попробуйте слово АЛЬПИЙСКАЯ -- оно тоже сматчится, хотя там нет всех тех символов, которые есть в регулярке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52086/discussion-between-dakemu-and-yuri).

Comment: вам нужны все символы или любой из перечисленных?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\b[ГОДРАЗНЯ]+\b/
```

`\b` - означает границу слова, т.е. регулярка будет искать слова состоящие только из букв, перечисленных в квадратных скобках.

2 раза писать `О` в скобках не нужно.
Так же сматчит слова `ГРАД`, `ГОРОД` и т.п.

Если не добавлять `\b` - сматчит все, где есть хоть одна буква из списка.